# new to c++: problem with function return type

Tags: c++, function

i'm very new to c++ and i'm trying to reproduce a program that's written in my textbook. the text for it is below and i've copied it into an online IDE as it's written. however, i can't get it to compile because i get the error quoted below.

```
"error: functions that differ only in their return type
      cannot be overloaded"
```

any advice for how to get this error to go away? i have tried looking at other answers to related questions but i can't figure out how to adapt them to my situation.

thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int round(double number);

int main (){

  double doubleValue;
  char ans;

  do
  {

    cout << "Enter a double value: ";
    cin >> doubleValue;
    cout << endl << endl;

    cout << "Rounded that number is: " << round(doubleValue) << endl << endl;

    cout << "Again? (y/n): ";
    cin >> ans;

  } while(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');

  cout << "End of testing." << endl << endl;

  return 0;

}

int round(double number){

  return static_cast<int>(floor(number + 0.5));

}
```

Comment: Kick the habit of `using namespace std;`. It's a bad habit.

Comment: You've discovered a reason why you should completely forget that "using namespace std;" is a part of C++. Your definition conflicts with `std::round`, that `using namespace std;` injected into your global namespace, conflicting with your function. You will do yourself a favor by completely forgetting of its existence.

Comment: `round` is part of `cmath`, regardless of `using namespace std`, MSVC, g++ and clang all fail.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Whoever closed it should reopen it.

Comment: thank you, @SamVarshavchik! i probably never would've figured this out on my own. and thank you everyone else too!

Comment: qwerty Which compiler are you using? `round` would as @ChrisMM pointed out cause problems even without `using namespace std;` using the most common compilers.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, i'm using g++

Comment: @qwerty Ok, and was removing `using namespace std;` enough to solve the problem? I would expect it to still complain about ambiguity, like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/i-Z7yb)